# Unknown source of ClassCastException (in JTables)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, classcastexception

I'm presently refactoring a `JTable` which displays a multitude of different types of data. The primary reason for this refactoring is that there a few `ClassCastExceptions` (the author/friend who wrote the code is off on hiatus), and I can't seem to find where these are originating from. Due to the large codebase, I'm at a loss as to where to start. Does anyone have any suggestions? I realize and apologize for the ambiguity of this question!

I've included the stack trace below. Thanks!!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at javax.swing.JTable$BooleanRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can we see some of the table creation code? It looks like there's some place where there is a string but the table expects a boolean.

Comment: I would love to, but the code is all over the place. Very much a nightmare. I've come across what I think is the root problem though.

I should have mentioned that these exceptions occur when the contents of a row are sorted by a `TableRowSorter`. The problem is that the `JTable` columns (or rather one column) has multiple `CellRender`s it can select from, and when the sorting occurs the `CellRender`s don't change. I have a method which changes them accordingly now, but I'm not sure how to invoke a method after a sort.

Comment: A `RowSorterListener` listens for the sort, but unfortunately it invokes the code before the sort occurs, effecitvely making it useless.

So, I guess my current issue is figuring out how to invoke a method after a sort is finished. Any ideas? Thanks for all the help, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error which is occurring in `BooleanRenderer` is because it is expecting that the value that is from the table's model is of type `Boolean` and tries to cast to it (akf's answer has the exact line of code where it occurs).

My guess is that initially it was expected that the model would return `Boolean` values for the given column but at one point it is returning strings instead.
Therefore, I would concentrate on what model is being used for this given table (is it a custom model? Is it the default model where it is adding values to it?) and see where it may be getting a String instead of a `Boolean`.

Comment: Avrom, you're absolutely right - thanks. If you have a moment/if you're interested, see my above comment to mmeyers on the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the table contains a checkbox (when the column model states that the column contains type Boolean) and the renderer tries to convert the contents into a boolean. But probably the contents are just strings. The solution is to change the data in the table or to create your own renderer.

Comment: Bruno,

The contents weren't just Strings - which was my problem unfortunately. My column was containing all sorts of datatypes in addition to individual renderers. I didn't mention that explicitly, so that was my bad, but your idea would definitely have worked otherwise. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from your TableModel (jtable.getModel())
It said somewhere

```
(..)
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
   {
   switch(column)
     {
   (...)
      case XX: return Boolean.class;
      }
   }
```

but the value in your model in this column is a String

```
public Object getValueAt(int row,int column)
  {
  (..)
   switch(column)
     {
   (...)
      case XX: return (a String);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yep, it was - this helped a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To debug this problem, you may want to consider biting the bullet and putting a breakpoint in the `JTable$BooleanRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent()`  on the line that makes the cast

`setSelected((value != null && ((Boolean)value).booleanValue()));`

(from `JTable.java 1.288 06/11/15`)

and check the class type of `value`.  when you find a `String`, you can identify the offending column and row from your model.  That will at least give you a start on identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dig up an old question, but I ran into this issue myself & this post came up in a search and this is what I ran into.

I had JUnits tests fail (and actually throwing runtime exceptions) but I continued to run add/removes on my JTable (in the JUnit test) which put the GUI application in a bad state, and I would see the ClassCastException come up exactly as Chris had described.

So the "fix" for me was to make sure that all unit tests catch their exceptions and return failure **instead** of proceeding to run more unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the cause was exactly as Avrom specified.  In my case, I had the `getValueAt` implemented as:

```
@Override
synchronized public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
  if (row < m_rows.size()) {
    return m_rows.get(row).getValueAt(col);
  } 
  else 
  {
    return "";  // THIS IS THE BUG
  }
}
```

The problem here is that, is a row does not exist, a String is returned, for every column.  However some of my columns has the class type, Boolean, and hence the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
  at javax.swing.JTable$BooleanRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable.java:5409)
  at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5736)
```

The solution was simply to change the return value to:

```
return null;
```